# Системное время с точностью до наносекунд

Tags: c, linux

Как взять системное время с точностью до наносекунд?
Спасибо

Answer (score 6):

```
timespec ts;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
```

где timespec:

```
struct timespec {
        time_t   tv_sec;        /* seconds */
        long     tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
};
```

http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime

Answer (score 6):

В комментарий к совершенно правильному ответу @Anton Dobkin текст не помещается, пришлось ответом.

Вопрос лишь в том, **какое именно** время в наносекундах мы получаем (как его с пользой интерпретировать). Маленькая программка:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int  i, n = av[1]? atoi(av[1]): 10;
  if (n < 2)
    n = 10;
  struct timespec nt[n];


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&nt[i]);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("%ld sec %ld nsec (%ld)\n",
        (long)(nt[i].tv_sec-nt[i?i-1:i].tv_sec),
        nt[i].tv_nsec, nt[i].tv_nsec-nt[i?i-1:i].tv_nsec);
  exit (0);
}
```

Можно оттранслировать

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc -O3 nano.c -lrt
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
0 sec 41177457 nsec (0)
0 sec 41183591 nsec (6134)
0 sec 41189306 nsec (5715)
0 sec 41194933 nsec (5627)
0 sec 41200516 nsec (5583)
0 sec 41206296 nsec (5780)
0 sec 41211878 nsec (5582)
0 sec 41217648 nsec (5770)
0 sec 41223324 nsec (5676)
0 sec 41229074 nsec (5750)
```

а потом посмотреть

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 10000 |less
```

и получить богатую пищу для размышлений о том, *а что именно мы меряем*?

Желающие могут заменить `CLOCK_REALTIME` на `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` или `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` и еще больше задуматься.

Comment: Хмм... А это ведь можно использовать как начальное значение для получения псевдослучайного числа.

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
int
main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    int  i, n = av[1] ? atoi(av[1]) : 10;
    if (n < 2)
        n = 10;
    struct timespec nt[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &nt[i]);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        printf("%ld sec (%ld) | %ld nsec (%ld)\n",
            (long)(nt[i].tv_sec), (long)(nt[i].tv_sec - nt[i - 1].tv_sec),
            (long)(nt[i].tv_nsec), (long)(nt[i].tv_nsec - nt[i - 1].tv_nsec)
        );
    exit(0);
}
```

Выдача будет:

```
1525792118 sec (0) | 504833615 nsec (193)
1525792118 sec (0) | 504833657 nsec (42)
1525792118 sec (0) | 504833699 nsec (42)
1525792118 sec (0) | 504833741 nsec (42)
1525792118 sec (0) | 504833784 nsec (43)
1525792118 sec (0) | 504833830 nsec (46)
1525792118 sec (0) | 504833876 nsec (46)
1525792118 sec (0) | 504833920 nsec (44)
1525792118 sec (0) | 504833965 nsec (45)
```